# How to mock PHP's own methods using PHPUnit

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I want to add test coverage to a method inside a PHP class which invokes a PHP-built-in method. To be able to mock `copy()`, I had to create a wrapper class. **Is there a better way to mock PHP's built-in methods?** By "better", I mean that I do not want to introduce a wrapper class just for the sake of the unit testing.

I've checked [these docs](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/test-doubles.html#mock-objects) but could not find an answer.

I use PHP and PHPUnit only for a side project, therefore I might overlook something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify filesystem operations in a unit test I usually rely on [vfsStream](https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream). It's a virtual filesystem wrapper that allows you to test all operations on an in-memory filesystem.

If you just want to mock a built-in function, there's [php-mock](https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock).